# How can I find the number of components in DFS using c?

Tags: c

well, i traversed the DFS but now I just can't find components. Is there any way to solve it.

```
for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    for (j=1;j<=n;j++){
        printf("Enter the number of array position a[%d][%d] = ",i,j);
        scanf("%d",&ar[i][j]);
    }
}
DFS(v);
printf("\n");

for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if(reach[i]==1){
        count++;
    }
}
printf("Number of Components: %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What component are talking about? Also please make your code complete, where is main? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: well, i wanted to find the components of an matrix using DFS.

Comment: You are given an adjacency matrix after providing the number vertices of a graph. Find the
number of components in that Graph using DFS.
Sample Input:
4
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
1 1 0 0
Sample Output:
Number of Components 1.

Comment: You mean number of connected component from adjacency matrix. Is that okay

Comment: yes. it is. but i just.....

Comment: Are you sure that the array indices should be 1-based with `&ar[i][j]`? It's unusual.

Comment: well, that's the quest.

Comment: @TowfiqDemon can you please make it clear which comment you are replying to? It also pings the user if they aren't looking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm for the task:

```
Components = 0; 

For every vertex index i:
   if marks[i] == 0 then
      ++Components
      DFS(i)

DFS(v):
   marks[v] = Components
   for all vertices j adjacent to v:
      if marks[j] == 0:
         DFS(j)
```

Components store the the number of `components` and `marks[n]` represents the component number to which the vertex `n` belongs to.